# Laravel 5 redirect with message

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

Can someone explain why the code below does not work when it redirects to another page?

```
return redirect()->route('homepage')->with('message', 'I am so frustrated.');
```

The redirect works as expected, but the message does not appear.

The view looks like:

```
@if ( session()->has('message') )
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">{{ session()->get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

When I change it to:

```
return redirect()->route('contact')->with('message', 'I am so frustrated.');
```

, which is the same as **redirect()->back()**, everything works fine and the message is displayed. What is the difference between redirect `back()` and `to()` another view?

Comment: return redirect()->to('/')->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!') this is how i've used it before.

Comment: I have tried everything Redirect::to(), redirect()->to(), redirect()->route('homepage'),

Comment: Put  this in controller :- redirect('/contact')->with('message', 'I am so frustrated.') then in view {{ Session::get('message') }}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on Laravel 5.2, make sure all the routes you're using that access session data are contained in the `web` middleware group.

If your `contact` route is inside the `web` middleware group, but your `homepage` route is not, that would explain your issue.

Comment: YES this is propably the reason. I did not test it yet. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently on Laravel 5.7 [HTTP Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects) and this code worked for me in the Controller:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return $this->registered($request, $user) ?: 
    redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('success', 
    'An activation link was send to your email address.');
}
```

And in the View (etc.blade.php) i do:

```
@if(session('success'))
     <span class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ session('success') }}</strong>
     </span>
@endif
```